# Show in template internal array meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm working with Meteor and want to reach values that are stored in a field which functions as an internal array.

When I run the query (with projection) I get one record which looks like that:

```
{ "comments" : [ { "uid" : "1", "un" : "Sarah", "c" : "cc" }, { "uid" : "2", "un" : "Leo", "c" : "dd" } ] }
```

I need to show in a template "un" and "c" of each record in the array.
I tried that:

html:

```
<template name="allComments">
    <ul>
        {{#each allC}}
            <li>{{un}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.allComments.allC = function () {
    //query that returns result as above
}
```

I've tried also `{{#with}}`, nested `{{#each}}` and nested templates but it doesn't work..

How can I reach this value?

Thanks a lot, Sarah.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JS:

```
Template.allComments.helpers({
  allC: function() {
    //query that returns result as above
  }
});
```

'#each' should then work in your template.

Comment: What if you use {{#each allC.comments}}?

Comment: Have you double-checked that your allC method indeed returns that record?

Comment: when I run the query on a terminal this is the result. The query is:         result = TasksList.find({_id: Session.get('selectedID')}, {
            _id: false,
            title: false,
            createdAt: false,
            details: false,
            userID: false,
            userName: false,
            like: false,
            likeList: false
        });
         return result;}

Comment: Can you print the result in console and post the object it returned?

Comment: when I run  now in console:  db.tasks.find({_id: "noM2n5FHa3bEDNW"}, {_id: false,title: false, createdAt: false, details: false, userID: false, userName: false, like: false, likeList: false, deleted:false}) I get:  { "comments" : [ { "uid" : "Hj6B2uukDjb8ZRW", "un" : "Sarah", "c" : "dd" }, { "uid" : "Hj6B2uukDjb8ZRW", "un" : "Sarah", "c" : "as" } ] }

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to show this comments with:

```
Template.allComments.helpers({
allC: function () {
    var result=[];
    TasksList.findOne({_id:Session.get('selectedID')})['comments'].forEach(function(entry){
        result.push(entry['un']+entry['c']);
        });
    return result;
    },});
```

and

```
<template name="allComments">
<ul>
    {{#each allC}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```